# Android TabHost - setCurrentTab() does not change the tab content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have the problem that the tab content does not change when I use tabHost.setCurrentTab(...). One can see, that the corresponding tab is marked as active, the content stays the same. When I click on the tab, the content changes.

To the Setup.

I have different functionalities in one app using fragments. One fragment contains a tabhost. Each tab has its own layout and the fragment should switch between those tabs and show a selection of tabs depending on the state of the app.

I'll try to quote the important code passages.

The main xml file of the fragment:

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_master_emg_start"
                android:layout_height="445dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"/>

           <include layout="@layout/fragment_master_emg_setup"
                android:layout_height="445dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"/>

    ... some more includes

    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The xml files included just contain a relative layout and a bunch of buttons and textviews.

The Fragments onCreate Method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get View
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master_emg, container, false);
    Button button= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("test");
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    // Tabs
    // Setup - Start Tab

    TabHost.TabSpec t=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab0");
    t.setContent(R.id.master_emg_start);
    t.setIndicator("EMG Measurement - Setup");
    tabHost.addTab(t);

    TabHost.TabSpec t0=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    t0.setContent(R.id.master_emg_setup);
    t0.setIndicator("Setup");
    tabHost.addTab(t0);

    .... more tabs
    ....

    // Set initial visibility
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

   // Buttons to switch tabs

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    });
```

I've just included two tabs in this excerpt, but this would be the basic procedure.

I've tried to invalidade the tab host in order to have everythin redrawn. This did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here for this problem solution:

**Use :**

```
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabNumber);
```

Instead of :

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(tabNumber);
```